# Редирект на главную страницу Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, аутентификация

Через какое-то время, если обновить страницу, авторизованного пользователя перенаправляет на страницу login, по дефолту. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы его редиректило на главную, т.е. на '/' ?

Answer (score 1):

В файле `/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` есть конструкция, куда перенаправлять

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/login'); // куда душе угодно
}
```

**UPD: Исходя из новых данных**

Если все из коробки, то в `/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

нужно сделать следующее:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

заменить на

```
use AuthenticatesUsers {
    logout as oldLogout;
}
```

и в файле реализовать метод `logout`

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->oldLogout($request);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Об этой конструкции я знаю, но, я так понимаю, что с ее помощью осуществляется переходи после того как пользователь прошел авторизацию. Другими словами, если добавить return redirect('/') - все равно редиректит на /login.

Comment: если пользователь прошел авторизацию, в `LoginController.php` в переменную `$redirectTo` ставится путь, куда его направить

Comment: может у вас есть другой `middleware`? на сколько кастомный проект тут нужно знать

Comment: Мне кажется, надо переформулировать вопрос так: Как изменить редирект logout? Авторизация/Регистрация из коробки, создавалась вот таким способом php artisan make:auth.

Comment: @YuriGo обновил ответ

Comment: Хм...сделал все как вы написали, все равно редиректит на public/login, и выдает ошибку: InvalidArgumentException Route [welcome] not defined. Это при том, что роут welcome все таки есть..

Comment: а кэш приложения не пробовали почистить?)

Comment: попробуй это `$this->oldLogout($request);` убрать и вместо него поставь `$this->guard()->logout();`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71915/discussion-between-yurigo-and-maxkrasnov).